# Want to determine convert time as per specific time zone

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am receiving a DateTime object from external system.
I receive  a date like `2012-06-20T13:30:00+05:30`. 
The external system has created the date using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API.

I am not able to find the corresponding Date format for this. 
Moreover I want to convert the time to `09:00:00+01:30` (different time zone).

Comment: What is `2012`? What is `06`? What is `20`? What is `13`? What is `30`? What is `00`? Etc...? That's how you figure out a date format.

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29

Comment: As I understand, you want to convert joda `DateTime` to java `Date` in different zone?

Answer (score 1):

That String represents a date, a time-of-day, and an offset from [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

An positive offset means "ahead of UTC", to the east. A negative means "behind UTC", to the west. In your example, `+05:30` is modern [India time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_India).

This format is formally defined by the ISO 8601 standard. This standard is very useful. Be sure to read [the Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, and the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29), use ISO 8601 extensively. That format is the default for both parsing and generating string representations of date-time values.

Simply pass that string to the constructor of a DateTime. And pass a time zone object to constructor. Or later call `withZone` method to adjust the time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTimeParis = new DateTime( myIsoString, timeZoneParis );
```

I am confused by your reference to an offset of `+01:30`. I do not see such an offset in the [list of time zones](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Such an offset was [used for a decade](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_Standard_Time) in historical South Africa.